# How to update a global variable across multiple functions in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
counter = 0
def function_1():
  func_2(counter)

def func_2(counter):
  func_3(counter)

def func_3(counter):
   counter += 1
```

My goal is to keep track of counter incrementation in `func_3()` in all other functions.

I tried to make counter `global`

```
counter = 0
def function_1():
  global counter
  func_2(counter)

def func_2(counter):
  func_3(counter)

def func_3(counter):
   counter += 1
```

but it does not work, the counter incrementation is just local to `func_3()`

Any hints?

Comment: Why do you pass counter as an argument if it's available from the global scope? Int integer are copied, not referenced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: Counter is local in func_3 because you are passing it as a argument, which is local to the function. If you would like to have it global, you need to put global to func_3 (as you have it in function_1) and remove argument (that counter in ()). And King's jester comment is useful, there is a lot of information in that thread.

Comment: Thank you @politinsa, I realise now how silly I've been :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find an easy to understand explanation for you, but they all seemed to complicated.

The reason that you are seeing `counter` as a local variable inside your functions is because you are defining it in the function definition: `def func_2(counter):`.

To use the global `counter` inside a function you need to do it like this:

```
counter = 0

def function_1():
  func_2()

def func_2():
  func_3()

def func_3():
   global counter
   counter += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, @politinsa comment made me realise my error, if counter is of global scope, why did I pass it as an argument? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `globals().update(locals())`, example:

```
counter = 0
def function_1():
  func_2()

def func_2():
  func_3()

def func_3():
  counter += 1
  globals().update(locals())
```

or use `global` method

```
counter = 0
def function_1():
  func_2()

def func_2():
  func_3()

def func_3():
  global counter
  counter += 1
```